# Accurately placing multiple controls in a row programmatically with dynamic table layout panel

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, tablelayoutpanel

I have made a gui that correctly positions a checkbox and label controls to the form but read on here that to add scrolling the controls should be in a tableLayoutPanel and here using the same code is wrong. I have tried myriad ways to adapt the code and have now got in a mess with it, I am sure its a basic oversight but I cannot spot it.

**Code without tableLayoutPanel**

```
    int X = 1;
    string s = "i=";
    private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= X; i++)
        {
            //make the objects for list items
            Label lbl = new Label();
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
       
            lbl.Location = new Point(50, 75 * (i ));
            cb.Location = new Point(30, 75 * (i ));

            lbl.Text = s + i.ToString() + "  " + lbl.Location.ToString();
            //lbl.Text = txtBoxInput.Text;
            Controls.Add(lbl);
            Controls.Add(cb);
        }
        X++;
        txtBoxInput.Clear();
    }
```

[image: Snippet of desired performance from above code - works as desired]

**Code with TableLayoutPanel not working as desired**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createTableLayoutPanel();
    }

    int count = 1;
    int X = 1;
    string s = "i=";
    TableLayoutPanel table = new TableLayoutPanel();

    private void createTableLayoutPanel() 
    {
        

        table.ColumnCount = 2;
        table.RowCount = 0;
        table.BackColor = Color.Khaki;
        table.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 400);
        table.Location = new Point(50, 100);
        table.AutoScroll = true;

        Controls.Add(table);
    }

    private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TableLayoutPanel tlp = this.table;
        for (int i = 1; i <= X; i++)
        {

            //make the objects for list items
            Label lbl = new Label();
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

            table.SuspendLayout();
            //table.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
            //table.RowCount = table.RowCount + 1;
            //table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 50F));

            table.Controls.Add(cb, 0, i);

            lbl.Text = "i=" + i.ToString() + " " + txtBoxInput.Text + "  X=" + X.ToString();
            table.Controls.Add(lbl, 2, i);
            table.ResumeLayout();
        }
        X++;
        
        txtBoxInput.Clear();
    }
}
```

[image: Snippet of the undesired result with TLP used]

**Desired behaviour**
When Add item is clicked a row should be added to the top of the TLP and move any existing rows downwards. Checkbox always on the left, label always on the right.

Comment: how many columns do you have? to which column you are trying add label ?

Comment: btw ... you know that CheckBox has it's own label already and you can access it with Text property?

Comment: Hi, I wanted 2 columns, checkbox in left column, label in the right column, and no i didn't know that checkbox had its own label :-( thanks Selvin

Comment: 2 column? indexes are 0 based ... now look at your code when you are adding label

Comment: I wasn't sure about the zero based indexing, i still get garbled outputs when i change the indexes to 0 and 1. Great comment about the checkbox label - that solves one issue, but i would still like to know how to solve this issue in case i used a different control.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if you used a DataGridView, with a CheckBoxColumn and a TextBoxColumn (read-only, if required)? -- Note also that the CheckBox and the Label Controls have different internal Padding (4px on top, IIRC), so alignment can also be an issue -- If you need to fill the TLP bottom-up, you need to maintain a collection of these Controls (e.g., a `List<tuple>`), clear the TLP's child Controls when a new Row is added, insert a new tuple in the collection at index `0`, then add all Controls back

Comment: I will edit the code to have the correct indexes and credit you.

Comment: Hi Jimi, I read on here that to have a scroll on the panel i should use tablelayoutpanel so that's why i chose it. But i will try out the suggestion of the DGV

Comment: To have *something* that scrolls, you need a ScrollableControl (e.g., any Panel) as container and a Control that can auto-size. A DataGridView can of course do that. You may find it intrinsically more flexible in a similar scenario. But this, overall, depends on what you're actually trying to achieve and how much time you have (clearly, each complex Control has its own learning curve)

Comment: Thanks Jimi, i've not been on C# all that long but have some time at the moment to learn so i will be trying that out. I only saw mention of tablelayoutpanle and flow layout so this is the first time i have come across data grid.